# How can I optionally force some derived classes to implement an abstract method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I have a base `MappedViewModel`, that is, it is built for 'automatic' mapping to and from domain and other models:

```
public abstract class MappedViewModel<TEntity> : ViewModel
{
    public virtual void MapFromEntity(TEntity entity, bool forCreate = false)
    {
        Mapper.Map(entity, this, typeof(TEntity), GetType());
        if (ModelPurpose == ViewModelPurpose.Create)
        {
            NullifyReferenceProperties();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity MapToEntity()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<TEntity>(this);
    }

    protected virtual void NullifyReferenceProperties()
    {            
    }
}
```

I somehow feel that `NullifyReferenceProperties` should be abstract in the base class, to force classes that need it to implement it, but many classes don't need it, and many that need it when the model is not built for creating a new entity. Is it OK like it is now as `virtual`, or is there some way I can determine how to enforce its use?

Maybe a base `MappedViewModel` with a derived `MappedViewModelForCreate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force **ALL** classes derived from `MappedViewModel` to override the `NullifyReferenceProperties` method make it `abstract`. If not, I think it's better to just leave it `virtual`.

Comment: This is acceptable, as most `MappedViewModel` models will be generated via T4 from a data model, and an empty `NullifyReferenceProperties` can be easily added to all generated classes to satisfy the implementation requirement if I do make it `abstract`.